# How to best manage multi-lingual presentations?

Tags: latex, translation, beamer

I have a presentation done in Latex+Beamer, currently in french. I also need to make the same presentation, with the same structure, in dutch. I'd like to maintain the presentation in one file, so that if I want to change the structure of it, I only have to do it in one place. What's the best way to put the translations outside of the presentation file?

I thought of defining a command for each text element to be present in the slides, and having a different command definition for each language. But it seems quite heavy....

Thanks in advance

RAph

Answer (score 1):

I've seen only one solution to this (as part of the `babel` package) — you wrap each contiguous unit of text in a command that looks like this:

```
\langswitcher{french text}{dutch text}
```

and then define `\langswitcher` in the preamble to output either the first or the second argument.

I know this does not put the translation into a separate file, but this is simple, fast, works for sure, and probably solves your problem.

To put a translation in a separate file, at the very least you'll have to identify each piece of text anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
\newcommand{\en}{#1}
\newcommand{\de}{}
```

And in the text use:

```
\en{ my text in english }
\de{ german text }
```

And after I'd simply swap the commands.
Be aware that result should be different only because the text should take more or less space. You can cheat a bit using \phantom command.
This solution use only one file though.

Answer (score 0):

keep each slide in its own file... then \input{dutch-file} \input{french-file}